# how to implement basic search in django?

Tags: python, django

The searchbox gets the data but it doesn't show any results.
This is my code so far:

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
    q = request.GET['q']
    books = Advent.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'books': books, 'query': q})
else:
    return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'^your_url/?$', 'myblog.views.search', name='your_url_name'),
```

**search_results.html**

```
<p>You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>

{% if books %}
<p>Found {{ books|length }} book{{ books|pluralize }}.</p>
<ul>
    {% for book in books %}
    <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No books matched your search criteria.</p>
{% endif %}
```

**index.html**

```
<form type="get" action=".">
<input type="search" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Search..."/>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted here.

Comment: But it still won't work. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: Post the view and the template that the search form comes from; there could be a mistake there...?

Comment: Sure, here is the template: `<form type="get" action=".">

<input type="search" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Search..."/>

</form>`

Comment: Please, edit your question and put that source there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correct understand your problem, form send request on incorrect address, change action attribute:

```
<form type="get" action="{% url 'your_url_name' %}">
```

and then form will send the request to the correct address and not on the index.html

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

**views.py:**

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(['GET'])
def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    if q:
        books = Advent.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
        return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'books': books, 'query': q})
    return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

**index.html:**

```
<form type="get" action="{% url 'your_url_name' %}" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="search" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Search..."/>
</form>
```

The view requires GET methods. You also don't need the `else` statement, and you can move getting the query outside of the `if` statment. This will shorten your code a little.

In your HTML, you needed to change your action request to a proper url. If you do not have the write url mapped between your form and your view, it will not know what to do when the form is submitted.