# Django model search won't return any values

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a search function that will return the corresponding values in the table based on the `id` or `asset_name` but it's not returning anything when I search for a valid `id` or `asset_name`. Is there something I'm missing in my code?

Views.py

```
def search(request):
template = 'blog/home.html'  

query = request.GET.get('q') 

if query:
    results = Post.objects.filter(Q(id__icontains=query) | Q(asset_name__icontains=query))
else:
    results = Post.objects.filter(status="Published")

context = {
    'query': query
}
return render(request, template, context)

class PostListView(ListView):
model = Post
template_name = 'blog/home.html' 
context_object_name = 'posts'
ordering = ['-date_posted']
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
path('results/', search, name='search'),
]
```

Home.html

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
 <input type="text" name="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}" placeholder="Search for project" />
 <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<tbody>
{% for post in posts %}
<tr data-href="linkToFile.pdf"> 
<td>{{ post.id }}{% if query %}&q={{query}}{% endif %}</td>
<td><a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.asset_name }}{% if query %}&q={{query}}{% endif %}</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: are you sure the value of `query` variable is not ***empty***?

Comment: what's the value you get in `query = request.GET.get('q') `?

Comment: @shafik I'm new to django but I added the search code to the home.html code snippet from where I'm getting the `query = request.GET.get('q')` from

Comment: @JPG is there a way I can check this?

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986303/how-to-implement-basic-search-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, you are not sending `posts` as a context in `search` view. Which is why the iteration `% for post in posts %}` isn't working. I think its simpler to use it like this:

Template

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'results' %}">
 <input type="text" name="q" value="{{query}}" placeholder="Search for project" />
 <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<tbody>
{% for post in posts %}
<tr data-href="linkToFile.pdf"> 
<td>{{ post.id }}{% if query %}&q={{query}}{% endif %}</td>
<td><a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.asset_name }}{% if query %}&q={{query}}{% endif %}</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

View

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html' 
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        query = request.GET.get('q') 
        if query:
           context['posts'] = Post.objects.filter(Q(id__icontains=query) | Q(asset_name__icontains=query))
           context['query'] = query
        return context
```

In this way, you can get search and list view using one `PostListView` view, also don't need to use extra view to show search results.